# What is the Difference between GetBlobReference and GetBlobReferenceFromServer?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Im trying to save some images to azure blob storage and there are 2 method to get reference of a blob
[GetBlobReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee772850.aspx) and [GetBlobreferenceFromServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.getblobreferencefromserver.aspx)
but I could not find the difference between the two.

Is There any difference between the two?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There're a few differences:

1. `GetBlobReference` is in the older version of storage client library (`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient`) while `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` is in the newer version of the storage client library (`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob`).
2. More importantly, `GetBlobReference` just gives you a reference to the blob. It won't tell you the type of the blob (`Block` or `Page`) where as `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` will tell you the blob type or in other words `GetBlobReference` will not make a round trip to the server where as `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` will.
3. Because `GetBlobReferenceFromServer` method makes a server roundtrip, the blob must be present in the storage. If you invoke this method on a non-existing blob, the method will throw an error.

Comment: Are there any particular use cases for one over the other?