# Speed of GetBlockBlobReference

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Does anyone know the spped of GetBlockBlobReference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.getblockblobreference?view=azure-dotnet when having many blockblobs? Like 1 million or more blockblobs in a single container. In my head it should be O(1) but I can't find anything related to this in the docs.

Comment: `GetBlockBlobReference` doesn't make a network call. It simply creates an instance of `CloudBlockBlob`.

Comment: @GauravMantri oh. I actually thought it did something over the network. Well then DownTextAsync must be near instant then. I am not talking about getting the file downloaded so size of blob doesn't matter. I am talking about the speed of which it finds the blob on the account.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you interested in finding blob's properties or something else. DownloadTextAsync will download the blob's contents as text so size of the blob matters. You may want to look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053679/what-is-the-difference-between-getblobreference-and-getblobreferencefromserver/18053958#18053958

Comment: @GauravMantri I am trying to see if more files in a container results in a longer lookup time. Think of like a mssql database with a table with no index.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want to find out if the blob exists or not? Will you be searching by blob's name?

Comment: @GauravMantri no. I am just curious about if the speed of making the GetBlockBlobReference followed by DownloadTextAsync get worse if there is added more blobs to the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196666/discussion-between-gaurav-mantri-and-mslot).

Answer (score 1):

According to this link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/05/10/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets/ (the partition section) a blob is partitioned on container name+blob name, so getting a specific blob should be near instant, not calculating in the time it takes to download the blob.

Keep in mind that the GetBlockBlobReference call doesn't make  a network call and therefore doesn't impact the lookup.